# Relative links are ignored by "Linked Questions"

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-questions, relative-links

Relative links to posts, such as [`[this one](/questions/1)`](/questions/1), do not show up under **Linked**. See? →

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/71353/absolute-and-relative-links-to-posts) suggests that relative links to posts are used ~1% as often as absolute links. Not an overwhelming rate, but that still adds up to quite a lot of ignored links. Personally, I've used relative links pretty often. It was slightly disappointing to realize that this habit had been counterproductive.

Comment: Whoa, didn't know that we could use relative links.  That could be pretty handy.

Comment: @JeffMercado The caveat is that only host-relative links (starting with `/`) are still supported; others once were but have been disabled.

Comment: Probably not the best idea anyway. Migration and web apps that consume the post body in some way will probably break those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is done; it may not catch *every* relative URL, but it should catch most of the ones used in practice. Links will update as the affected posts are edited.

Comment: Please note that I use the deleted answer to this question as a reference in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314058/what-should-be-done-with-the-feature-that-redirects-searches-for-numbers-to-the?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the update.