# "More linked questions" view does not show all linked questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, linked-questions

I have a favourite canonical question for PDO problems, ["How to squeeze error message out of PDO?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3726505)

It's been used many dozens of times, as the "linked" column on that question shows. In fact, there are so many entries that a "see more linked questions..." link appears.

However, the ["see more linked questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url:%22https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/*%22) page shows only three links, because the `url:` search pattern **is ignoring links in comments.**

This doesn't make sense. Can this be fixed?

Also, I notice the links in the comments are all in the

```
https://stackoverflow.com/q/3726505/
```

format, while the URL search filter on the "see more..." page, by default, looks for

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726505/*
```

if comments were included here, they would be ignored anyway. Shouldn't the pattern rather be

```
https://stackoverflow.com/q*/3726505/*
```

?

Comment: Good find.  What an obscure bug =)

Comment: a bug .. it should be fixed

Comment: It also misses direct links to answers that are done using the "share" button. (Since those don't contain the question ID.)

Comment: @Mysticial I'm not sure I follow, they do contain the question ID? (eg. `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126639/138112`) or do you mean something else?

Comment: These "http://stackoverflow.com/a/8391601/922184". `8391601` is the post ID and `922184` is the user ID. The question ID is `8389648` but is not in the URL.

Comment: @Mysticial ohh, I see. True. I wasn't sure initially whether that *should* be counted, but on second thought, it kinda makes sense!

Comment: Don't forget about relative links, [they should also be considered if possible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120678/relative-links-are-ignored-by-linked-questions)

Comment: Gahh, I was just wondering about this the other day.

Comment: Wasn't this (at least partially) fixed? When I click on the [see more linked questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3a%22http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fq*%2f3726505%2f*%22&lq=1) link it contains the wildcards

Comment: @BenCollins _"fixed a long time ago"_ -- what makes you think so? I just tested this at [The “I Get It” Reputation Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/165773) - clicking "See more.." link shows only one (of 10) questions that were displayed in "Linked" section. This "test" has reliably failing for me for last few months, how does that qualify as "fixed"?

Comment: @gnat the thing I was referring to was having a query pattern that captured both /question/* and /q/* links.  It does that now.  What you're getting at is a separate issue that I am currently reviewing.

Comment: @gnat I'm going to take on the issue you emphasized (and actually, in fairness, it's the one referred to by the title of the question).

Comment: @BenCollins you sir are a gentleman and a scholar. Both tests I tried demonstrate that bug is fixed indeed. _More linked..._ for "canonical PDO" now displays 43 questions, for "I get it" 13 linked questions are displayed. Thank you! One minor thing I noticed the page title is "_Unanswered_ Linked Questions" where "unanswered" doesn't seem to make sense

Comment: @Ben `43 questions linked` yay! Thank you!

Comment: @gnat I looked at the linked questions for your question, and the title was "Linked Questions".  Not sure why you would have seen something different.

Comment: @BenCollins hard to tell why is that; I just checked and re-checked it and no matter how I try, "more linked..." opens at the "hot" sub-tab, with "Unanswered" in the title (tried it also from other browser, logged out). Anyway, when I manually switch sub-tab to "active", title changes to normal, that's minor glitch of my local environment I guess

Comment: @gnat ah, I see.  You  meant the _page_ title, and I thought you meant the header next to the tabs.  I got it now.  I'll fix it shortly.

Answer (score 9):

Our approach to this will be to show a more true list of the linked questions when you click the "more linked questions" link, rather than relying on the search engine.  Limitations of search preclude it from being as accurate as we want in this case.  Also, it's worth pointing out for anyone interested that "Linked" here means questions for which there are links on this question page (embedded in the question, answers, or comments) or for which there are links on its page pointing to this one.

For example, Question A has an embedded link to Question B (A -> B).  When viewing Question A's page, you'll see Question B in the "Linked" list in the sidebar.  However, you'll also see Question A in the sidebar while viewing Question B, even though Question B may not have any embedded links to Question A.

Answer (score 5):

I agree, and it's pretty annoying!

This should be implemented because most of the time, the **related questions are found in the comments and not in the answers** *(links are not proper answers)*. And as you don't always have the knowledge/time to answer properly, you just leave a comment with the link in order to help the poster of the question.

The meta is a good example of place where related question are linked within comments.

For example see [this post that already has 2 "related comments"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158581/adding-links-to-google-webfont-sites-is-broken#comment-458678). We can even go further with the **Data StackExchange** to find [posts with the keyword *related* at the beginning of the comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/109262/comments-with-related). You can see this is something pretty common, so the "more linked question" should definitely show links from comments too! We get close to 300 results and that includes only the comments with that exact wording. By including other common wording the results go up really fast.

---

Maybe we could have an auto-comment a bit like the "possible duplicate" one, but with a way to "link" a post as related to another, and these would show on the page. That would look like *"related to: [link]"*.

---

Also, it would be nice if at the same time the "see more linked question" brought us to a page with the `is:question` filter. I mean, I don't necessarily want to see all the 27 answers of a question in the list *(and miss other related questions that could help me because they appear in page 2037)*. If I want to see all the answers on a question, I'll go on the link provided by the question.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with this request.

But even if it's implemented, there's still the issue that questions newly marked as duplicates of other questions won't appear in the list of linked questions (even if `closed:1` is given in the search query). That's because the search engine ignores the new duplicate blocks containing "This question already has an answer here" when indexing results. I've made a request for that [on another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172844). Maybe that can be merged into this request.