# Can't search on keywords with colon anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

E.g. [user:157882 p:selectonemenu p:column](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A157882+p%3Aselectonemenu+p%3Acolumn) fails with no results while I'd expect at least [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15009707). Putting the individual words in doublequotes doesn't help either.

I'm 100% certain that this way of searching has worked before. At least yesterday morning. I search regularly on exact JSF tags which has the syntax `namespace:tagname` and have always had successful matches.

Comment: Interesting - I agree that if feels there should be results; checking...

Comment: @Marc: Thank you. Try e.g. [user:157882 h:datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A157882+h%3Adatatable) for a search which should guaranteed return ["a lot" of results](https://www.google.com/search?q=balusc+%22h:datatable%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: actually, `user:157882 code:h:datatable` does return ["a lot" of results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A157882+code%3Ah%3Adatatable) - I can't get that to work for the `p:selectonemenu`, though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has now been corrected - it was a parsing oddity resulting from [some changes I deployed yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169038/135201).  I've further refined the term parsing so cases with some special characters such as this should be handled more appropriately.

The search [now has 2 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:157882%20p:selectonemenu%20p:column) (guaranteed value of 2 expires as soon as I hit post below this text box!), including the one you expected.