# "Url" search option should not ignore new version of duplicate links in the results

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

The search seems to ignore the new duplicate links when I search for linked questions. (These links have the heading "This question already has an answer here".)

An example for the question "Headers already sent by PHP":

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=url:%22https://stackoverflow.com/q%2a/8028957/%2a%22%20is: question%2aclosed:1

Notice that newer questions marked as duplicate are absent here, which indicates that the new duplicate links are being ignored. I'm making a request to include them.

Here are duplicates not mentioned in the example above:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956376/php-header-redirect-headers-already-sent-when-no-output-codeigniter?rq=1
- [headers already sent error - cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017921/headers-already-sent-error-cookies)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965613/php-headers-already-sent-error-on-2-line
- [**And more...**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22headers%20already%20sent%22%20closed:1)

Comment: Can you provide an example or two of duplicates that are missing from the search output?  The most recent one I see in the results is [PHP header redirection not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579818/php-header-redirection-not-working).  Are there newer ones not picked up by search?

Comment: @BenCollins: I've added them.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is by design.  The questions to which you refer are all closed, and closed questions are not shown in search results unless you specify a closed state in your search terms (as you demonstrate in your "and more" link).

However, you may be interested to know that a [UI improvement for finding linked questions is imminent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183256/136973).

Comment: No, even if I add "closed:1" to the example search query, new duplicate questions still won't appear in the search results.

Comment: @PeterO, I'll take a closer look to see if search is excluding questions incorrectly.  I've retagged as status-review.

Comment: @PeterO. unfortunately, you're right, but this is still by design.  As of recently, duplicates no longer contain links to the duplicated question in their bodies, which means the those posts will not appear in the results of the search query you specified (unless the OP of the duplicate explicitly links to the duplicated question).