# How do I search linked questions?

Tags: feature-request, support, search, linked-questions

After clicking the "see more linked questions…" on the right when viewing [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql?lq=1) (with many linked questions):

[image]

You're taken to [a question list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/23446377?lq=1) of linked questions.

Is there any way to search this list?

I realize [I may be able to search for questions closed as duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137503/how-to-find-all-questions-that-were-duplicates-of-another-question), but actually I'm looking for the opposite (essentially `closed:no`).

If not, can we make a way?

It seems to essentially be search results - is there a reason it was done differently?

Comment: See also: [Is it possible to limit the linked questions list using additional search criteria?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252798) - it seems that it's not possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to limit the linked questions list using additional search criteria?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252798/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-linked-questions-list-using-additional-search-criter)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Url" search option should not ignore new version of duplicate links in the results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172844/url-search-option-should-not-ignore-new-version-of-duplicate-links-in-the-resu)

Comment: I wouldn't call this is a duplicate of [Is it possible to limit the linked questions list using additional search criteria?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252798) or ["Url" search option should not ignore new version of duplicate links in the results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172844) because this is a [meta-tag:feature-request], while those aren't. I wouldn't personally care about so much, but experience suggests that being marked as a feature request makes something much more likely to be considered for implementation (case in point, the latter was simply marked as "by design").

Comment: Bernhard, [the answer from a former employee](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183869/282094), "This behavior is by design. The questions to which you refer are all closed, and closed questions are not shown in search results **unless** you specify a closed state in your search terms (as you demonstrate in your "and more" link)." is that you can either search differently, follow the link in the answer **or** ask for ***that*** to be fixed; not file a new request for a new feature to ignore an old bug (or lack of a complete implementation). I can't speak to the other suggested duplicate.

Comment: @Rob Actually scratch my last reply, that mostly applies only to [the first linked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252798). Regarding [the second linked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172844), I'm not asking about the "url" search option, that works differently from "linked questions" (it only considers links in posts, not in comments or answers as well, like "linked" does), so that would be quite distinct from this.

Comment: @Rob As a side note, "file a new request for a new feature to ignore an old [by-design] 'bug'" is pretty much exactly what I've explicitly seen staff say multiple times over the years. But then you do also say "ask for that to be fixed", so maybe I'm simply misunderstanding what you meant (which I suppose I'm not too sure about in any case).

Comment: Bernhard, when a closing post is queued for review and then a duplicate is proposed the **automatically generated** comment starts with: "Does this answer your question?"; while it is possible to reply to the comment, and get **one** of the many people involved to respond, it's best to edit your question if it's not clear to potential other reviewers ***why*** the proposed duplicate (and any others you can find) are not duplicates, applicable, helpful. This is especially important when your "**new**" request is **several** years old - an edit will (fairly, hopefully) bump it.

Comment: Since the that time there have been new methods and changes detailed in my comment. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176984/282094 and comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137503/how-to-find-all-questions-that-were-duplicates-of-another-question/137504#comment707573_137504 in an answer to this duplicate question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137503/282094 and this newer comment about a forgotten bug: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209174/recently-active-linked-questions-updates-incorrectly#comment1179089_209174 by staff saying that it will be revisited.

Comment: Ironically all these proposed duplicates and comments go into a bidirectional linked list which hooks together all these tightly and loosely related posts. --- Determining which post (probably the newest) you want to re-ask and then editing the above question should result in a new decision about either: ensuring that the search tools have the necessary working parameters **or** that a search bar () is added to the linked list page (which you arrive at when you click on the "show more results") **if** that is how you would propose to implement a new Feature.