# "See more linked questions" only works one way

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-questions

If I understand correctly how the linked questions works; if the post Q1 contains a link to Q2 (anywhere on the page - in the comments, in the answers, in the question) then Q1 is shown among *linked questions* for Q1 and vice-versa.

When there are too many linked questions, a there is a link saying "see more linked questions", for example [here](see more linked questions).

After clicking on that link you get search of this form:
`url:"http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/xxxxx/*"`
But this only returns questions linking **to** the given question and the ones which are linked **from** it.

For example, if I would click on this link for Q1, I would not see Q2.

Is this intentional? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [different question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183256/) which also mentions problems with linked questions (namely the problems that the links given in comments might be missed) was tagged as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). When I tried this on some questions, linked questions do not link to a search anymore and they seem to work as expected.

I am posting this answer here, so that the post does not remain unanswered (the issue is already solved).